# General database design - can I reference field names in other tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, audit

I have a table with various fields that can be updated.  Let's called it `table1` and assume it has these fields:

```
user VARCHAR2
first_name VARCHAR2
last_name VARCHAR2
```

My question: I want to keep track of edits to these fields.  I have an application that allows these fields to be updated but I want to keep track of *when* a field is edited, *who* edited the field and *which* field was edited - the *which* is the bit I need help with.

I could have a history table:

```
date_edited DATE
who_edited VARCHAR2
field_name_edited VARCHAR2
```

what if the field name got changed though?.. It would mean that `field_name_edited` would refer to a non-existent field.  This seems like a silly approach.

There must be some common way of doing this sort of thing?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using an Oracle DB - see new question tags.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Theoretically the fieldname would refer to the DBMS catalog. In practice, it is often discouraged by the DBMS to link to the catalogs, because it could easily mix up DDL and DML.

Comment: Is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-jul/o48totalrecall-092147.html overkill?

Comment: @wildplasser - try getting a DBA to let you touch the DBMS catalog :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "There must be some common way of doing this sort of thing?"

Not really, because your approach is a common but misguided one.   Tracking changes at the column level is unsatisfactory for several reasons:

1. It gets expensive when an update touches several columns (inserting multiple audit records for each updated row).
2. It's hard to assemble a coherent picture of the state of the record at a given point in time (programmatically complex, and more expensive to boot).
3. There's no elegant way to test whether a given column has been changed.
4. Storing the column value is messy (implementations usually handle different data-types by converting them to strings).

(Your suggested table doesn't deal with that last point, which I presume is an oversight: there's little value to an audit trail which doesn't track the changed values).

So, what is the common solution?  Row-level history tables.  With triggers which insert the whole record into the journalling table (together with those metadata columns like DATE_EDITED and WHO_EDITED).  These triggers can easily be generated from the data dictionary.

It is true that this approach makes it harder to spot which columns were edited in any given transaction.   However:

1. it is hard but not impossible to do this.  It can be implemented in SQL (using analytic LAG or something) but actually the human being is pretty good at spotting changes unaided.
2. the cost of this is borne by the audit sub-system, which in real life - and regardless of what the requirements say - will not be used much, and certainly much less than the core part of the application.  So it is better to offload processing costs on to the audit sub-system, rather than making the journalling expensive.

And, as I said, row-level journalling incurs lower costs than column-level both in generating the audit records and retrieving them.

---

In your comment you link to a piece about Oracle's [Total Recall product](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-jul/o48totalrecall-092147.html).  This is actually a very elegant solution, which has a very low impact on the main system, and which makes it easy to recover the historical state of our tables.  The problem is, prior to 12c it is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition which makes it expensive.  (In fact it is now part of the [Advanced Compression option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594/options.htm#CJACCDBA) rather than a separate product in its own right).  In 12c Basic Flashback Data Archive (the new name for Total Recall) is [available in all editions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC116), but we still need to buy the Advanced Compression Option to compress the journalling tables.

---

> "You recommend [to store] row edits and thus, store redundand data. "

Yep.  Storage is usually cheap these days.  The cost of storing redundant data is usually a good price to pay for efficient writing and retrieval of records.

> " You still need to copy the literal names of the original columns"

Journalling uses one audit table for each data table; the audit table matches  the structure of the live table, with some additional columns to hold metadata relating to the transaction.  We would expect the audit columns to have the same names as their analogous data columns.  (Doing anything else would be stupid, not least because we can generate DDL for the audit tables from the data dictionary.)

Comment: +1 nice answer.  You sound correct: I can see why my approach is probably misguided.  Thank you.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your answer, probably also bc I'm no native speaker. You recommend not to track column edits, but row edits and thus, store redundand data. How does this get rid of referencing the "journalling table"'s column names? (whatever this is). You still need to copy the literal names of the original columns, right?

Comment: @Blauhirn - sorry you couldn't understand my answer.  I have edited it to clarify the points you raise.  I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: *This is what I've used for a similar situation a couple of years ago. I didn't like it too much then with all the joins and the triggers we had to do. If someone has a better approach, please post!*

From what I understand, if you think the field names could change, you should have a master data table that keeps track of field information. You'll need to have one history table for the master data and one for the actual user table.
Like one of the posters above has said, you could use triggers to write to the correct history table when one of the tables is modified.

```
table editable_fields

id
field_name
created/modified_by/date
```

sample entries = {(1, user), (2, first_name), (3, last_name)}

---

```
table user

id
field1_value
field2_value
field3_value
created/modified_by/date
```

sample entries = {(1, johnsmith, John, Smith), (2, janedoe, Jane, Doe)}

---

```
table user_fields_mapping

id
-- FKs to editable_fields.id
field1_editable_id
field2_editable_id
field3_editable_id
```

sample entries = {(1, 1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2, 3)}